# How can I use this animation code?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, iphone-sdk-3.0

I'm a newbie and I need some help.

I want to display a popup image over a given UIView, but I would like it to behave like the UIAlertView or like the Facebook Connect for iPhone modal popup window, in that it has a bouncy, rubbber-band-like animation to it.

I found some code on the net from someone who was trying to do something similar.  He/she put this together, but there was no demo or instructions.

Being that I am so new, I don't have any idea as to how to incorporate this into my code.

This is the routine where I need the bouncy image to appear:

```
- (void) showProductDetail
{
. . .
    ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    // THIS IS A STRAIGHT SCALE ANIMATION RIGHT NOW. I WANT TO REPLACE THIS 
    // WITH A BOUNCY RUBBER-BAND ANIMATION
        _productDetail.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(0.1,0.1);
        [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
        [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.5];
        _productDetail.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(1,1);
        [UIView commitAnimations];      
    }
. . .
}
```

This is the code I found:

```
float pulsesteps[3] = { 0.2, 1/15., 1/7.5 };
- (void) pulse {
    self.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(0.6, 0.6);
    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:pulsesteps[0]];
    [UIView setAnimationDelegate:self];
    [UIView setAnimationDidStopSelector:@selector(pulseGrowAnimationDidStop:finished:context:)];
    self.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(1.1, 1.1);
    [UIView commitAnimations];
}

- (void)pulseGrowAnimationDidStop:(NSString *)animationID finished:(NSNumber *)finished context:(void *)context {   
    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:pulsesteps[1]];
    [UIView setAnimationDelegate:self];
    [UIView setAnimationDidStopSelector:@selector(pulseShrinkAnimationDidStop:finished:context:)];
    self.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(0.9, 0.9);
    [UIView commitAnimations];
}

- (void)pulseShrinkAnimationDidStop:(NSString *)animationID finished:(NSNumber *)finished context:(void *)context {
    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:pulsesteps[2]];
    self.transform = CGAffineTransformIdentity;
    [UIView commitAnimations];
}
```

Thanks in advance for any help that you can give me.

Comment: You should accept Felixyz's answer if it has solved your problem.

Answer (score 2):

It's pretty simple. In your `showProductDetail` method, you start an animation block, then set the `_productDetail.transform` property, and then commit the block. This is what makes the animation happen.

The code that you found is designed to do a chain of such animations, but the property being modified is on `self` instead of on `_productDetail`. If `_productDetail` is an instance of a class that you created yourself, you can put the animation code inside that class.

Otherwise, just move the code inside the `pulse` method to the `showProductDetail` method, and put the two other methods below that method. Replace `self.transform`with `_productDetail.transform`in all three methods.